# duda con el resultado de un arreglo

Tags: javascript, promesas, fetch

tengo una duda respecto al resultado de un arreglo que creo en una iteracion y no se del por que es el codigo es el siguiente:
Este pedazo de codigo es un objeto el cual voy a usar para ir manejando dinamicamente una direccion  que voy a traer con la funcion fecth()

```js
const dataSet = {
    "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-MD.A" : ["Maryland", {lat: 39.063946, lng: -76.802101}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-AL.A" : ["Alabama", {lat: 32.806671, lng: -86.791130}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-AK.A" : ["Alaska", {lat: 61.370716, lng: -152.404419}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-AZ.A" : ["Arizona", {lat: 33.729759, lng: -111.431221}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-AR.A" : ["Arkansas", {lat: 34.969704, lng: 92.373123}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-CA.A" : ["California", {lat: 36.116203, lng: -119.681564}],
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-CO.A" : ["Colorado", {lat: 39.059811, lng: -105.311104}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-CT.A" : ["Connecticut",{lat: 41.597782, lng: -72.755371} ],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-DE.A" : ["Delaware", {lat: 39.318523, lng: -75.507141}] ,//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-DC.A" : ["District of Columbia", {lat: 38.897438, lng: -77.026817}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-FL.A" : ["Florida", {lat: 27.766279, lng: -81.686783}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-GA.A" : ["Georgia", {lat: 33.040619, lng: -83.643074}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-HI.A" : ["Hawaii", {lat: 21.094318, lng: -157.498337}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-ID.A" : ["Idaho", {lat: 44.240459, lng: -114.478828}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-IL.A" : ["Illinois", {lat: 40.349457, lng: -88.986137}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-IN.A" : ["Indiana", {lat: 39.849426, lng: -86.258278}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-IA.A" : ["Iowa", {lat: 42.011539, lng: -93.210526}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-KS.A" : ["Kansas", {lat: 38.526600, lng: -96.726486}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-KY.A" : ["Kentucky", {lat: 37.668140, lng: -84.670067}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-LA.A" : ["Louisiana", {lat: 31.169546, lng: -91.867805}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-ME.A" : ["Maine", {lat: 44.693947, lng: -69.381927}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-MA.A" : ["Massachusetts", {lat: 42.230171, lng: -71.530106}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-MI.A" : ["Michigan", {lat: 43.326618, lng: -84.536095}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-MN.A" : ["Minnesota", {lat: 45.694454, lng: -93.900192}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-MS.A" : ["Mississippi", {lat: 32.741646, lng: -89.678696}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-MO.A" : ["Missouri", {lat: 38.456085, lng: -92.288368}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-MT.A" : ["Montana", {lat: 46.921925, lng: -110.454353}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-NE.A" : ["Nebraska", {lat: 41.125370, lng: -98.268082}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-NV.A" : ["Nevada", {lat: 38.313515, lng: -117.055374}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-NH.A" : ["New Hampshire", {lat: 43.452492, lng: -71.563896}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-NJ.A" : ["New Jersey", {lat: 40.298904, lng: -74.521011}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-NM.A" : ["New Mexico", {lat: 34.840515, lng: -106.248482}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-NY.A" : ["New York", {lat: 42.165726, lng: -74.948051}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-NC.A" : ["North Carolina", {lat: 35.630066, lng: -79.806419}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-ND.A" : ["North Dakota", {lat: 47.528912, lng: -99.784012}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-OH.A" : ["Ohio", {lat: 40.388783, lng: -82.764915}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-OK.A" : ["Oklahoma", {lat: 35.565342, lng: -96.928917}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-OR.A" : ["Oregon", {lat: 44.572021, lng: -122.070938}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-PA.A" : ["Pennsylvania", {lat: 40.590752, lng: -77.209755}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-RI.A" : ["Rhode Island", {lat: 41.680893, lng: -71.511780}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-SC.A" : ["South Carolina", {lat: 33.856892, lng: -80.945007}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-SD.A" : ["South Dakota", {lat: 44.299782, lng: -99.438828}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-TN.A" : ["Tennessee", {lat: 35.747845, lng: -86.692345}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-TX.A" : ["Texas", {lat: 31.054487, lng: -97.563461}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-UT.A" : ["Utah", {lat: 40.150032, lng: -111.862434}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-VT.A" : ["Vermont", {lat: 44.045876, lng: -72.710686}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-VA.A" : ["Virginia", {lat: 37.769337, lng: -78.169968}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-WA.A" : ["Washington", {lat: 47.400902, lng: -121.490494}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-WV.A" : ["West Virginia", {lat: 38.491226, lng: -80.954453}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-WI.A" : ["Wisconsin", {lat: 44.268543, lng: -89.616508}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-WY.A" : ["Wyoming", {lat: 42.755966, lng: -107.302490}]//
}
```

aqui viene el siguiente pedazo de codigo lo comento ahi para explicarme de una manera mas comoda

```js
const keyDataSet = Object.keys(dataSet)//me devuelve un arreglo con el nombre de las propiedades
var locationsInfo = []//en este arreglo voy a guardar los objetos que voy a iterar mas abajo

const getLocations = () => {

for(let id of keyDataSet){
    
    
    fetch(`http://api.eia.gov/series/?api_key=707c8ecbdbd34cbb75272c7a4256ca6b&series_id=${id}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(locations =>{

       let locationData = {//creo un objeto donde guardo la informacion
            position:{//creo otro objeto
                 lat:dataSet[id][1].lat,lng:dataSet[id][1].lng},
            name:dataSet[id][0],
            year:locations.series[0].data[0][0], 
            CO:  locations.series[0].data[0][1]            
        }
        
        locationsInfo.push(locationData)  
  
    })   
}

}
```

el problema esta aca llamo la funcion de getLocations() 
despues imprimo el valor del arreglo que contine todos los objetos y me los imprime normalmente, pero despues imprimo la longitud de ese arreglo y me aparece cero y no se la verdad del por que pasa eso le agradeceria mucho si me dijeran del por que no se si es por el .then

```js
getLocations()
console.log(locationsInfo);//me arroja el arreglo con todos los objetos añadidos y con una medida de 51

console.log(locationsInfo.length);// pero aca me dice que ese arreglo tiene una medida de cero y quedo como WTF!
```

por otro lado cuando imprimo en consola me aparece esto: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que diferencia hay entre que el primer arreglo no me indique cuantos indices hay pero en el otro me indica que hay 30 indices, pero si yo abro el primero que me indica que  hay cero indices aparece esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que estas combinado llamadas sincronas con los las asíncronas que posee el `fetch`, por lo tanto, cuando realizas el llamado a `getLocations()` y todavía no termina de realizar todos los request. Lo que deberías hacer es retornar una promesa en la función `getLocation()` para así obtener el resultado una vez terminan todas las peticiones. Dejo el ejemplo:

```js
const dataSet = {
    "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-MD.A" : ["Maryland", {lat: 39.063946, lng: -76.802101}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-AL.A" : ["Alabama", {lat: 32.806671, lng: -86.791130}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-AK.A" : ["Alaska", {lat: 61.370716, lng: -152.404419}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-AZ.A" : ["Arizona", {lat: 33.729759, lng: -111.431221}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-AR.A" : ["Arkansas", {lat: 34.969704, lng: 92.373123}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-CA.A" : ["California", {lat: 36.116203, lng: -119.681564}],
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-CO.A" : ["Colorado", {lat: 39.059811, lng: -105.311104}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-CT.A" : ["Connecticut",{lat: 41.597782, lng: -72.755371} ],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-DE.A" : ["Delaware", {lat: 39.318523, lng: -75.507141}] ,//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-DC.A" : ["District of Columbia", {lat: 38.897438, lng: -77.026817}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-FL.A" : ["Florida", {lat: 27.766279, lng: -81.686783}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-GA.A" : ["Georgia", {lat: 33.040619, lng: -83.643074}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-HI.A" : ["Hawaii", {lat: 21.094318, lng: -157.498337}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-ID.A" : ["Idaho", {lat: 44.240459, lng: -114.478828}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-IL.A" : ["Illinois", {lat: 40.349457, lng: -88.986137}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-IN.A" : ["Indiana", {lat: 39.849426, lng: -86.258278}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-IA.A" : ["Iowa", {lat: 42.011539, lng: -93.210526}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-KS.A" : ["Kansas", {lat: 38.526600, lng: -96.726486}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-KY.A" : ["Kentucky", {lat: 37.668140, lng: -84.670067}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-LA.A" : ["Louisiana", {lat: 31.169546, lng: -91.867805}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-ME.A" : ["Maine", {lat: 44.693947, lng: -69.381927}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-MA.A" : ["Massachusetts", {lat: 42.230171, lng: -71.530106}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-MI.A" : ["Michigan", {lat: 43.326618, lng: -84.536095}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-MN.A" : ["Minnesota", {lat: 45.694454, lng: -93.900192}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-MS.A" : ["Mississippi", {lat: 32.741646, lng: -89.678696}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-MO.A" : ["Missouri", {lat: 38.456085, lng: -92.288368}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-MT.A" : ["Montana", {lat: 46.921925, lng: -110.454353}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-NE.A" : ["Nebraska", {lat: 41.125370, lng: -98.268082}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-NV.A" : ["Nevada", {lat: 38.313515, lng: -117.055374}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-NH.A" : ["New Hampshire", {lat: 43.452492, lng: -71.563896}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-NJ.A" : ["New Jersey", {lat: 40.298904, lng: -74.521011}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-NM.A" : ["New Mexico", {lat: 34.840515, lng: -106.248482}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-NY.A" : ["New York", {lat: 42.165726, lng: -74.948051}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-NC.A" : ["North Carolina", {lat: 35.630066, lng: -79.806419}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-ND.A" : ["North Dakota", {lat: 47.528912, lng: -99.784012}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-OH.A" : ["Ohio", {lat: 40.388783, lng: -82.764915}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-OK.A" : ["Oklahoma", {lat: 35.565342, lng: -96.928917}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-OR.A" : ["Oregon", {lat: 44.572021, lng: -122.070938}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-PA.A" : ["Pennsylvania", {lat: 40.590752, lng: -77.209755}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-RI.A" : ["Rhode Island", {lat: 41.680893, lng: -71.511780}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-SC.A" : ["South Carolina", {lat: 33.856892, lng: -80.945007}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-SD.A" : ["South Dakota", {lat: 44.299782, lng: -99.438828}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-TN.A" : ["Tennessee", {lat: 35.747845, lng: -86.692345}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-TX.A" : ["Texas", {lat: 31.054487, lng: -97.563461}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-UT.A" : ["Utah", {lat: 40.150032, lng: -111.862434}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-VT.A" : ["Vermont", {lat: 44.045876, lng: -72.710686}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-VA.A" : ["Virginia", {lat: 37.769337, lng: -78.169968}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-WA.A" : ["Washington", {lat: 47.400902, lng: -121.490494}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-WV.A" : ["West Virginia", {lat: 38.491226, lng: -80.954453}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-WI.A" : ["Wisconsin", {lat: 44.268543, lng: -89.616508}],//
 "EMISS.CO2-TOTV-TT-TO-WY.A" : ["Wyoming", {lat: 42.755966, lng: -107.302490}]//
}
const keyDataSet = Object.keys(dataSet);

const getLocations = () => {
    let data = [];
    let locationsInfo = [];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        for(let id of keyDataSet){
            data.push(
                fetch(`https://api.eia.gov/series/?api_key=707c8ecbdbd34cbb75272c7a4256ca6b&series_id=${id}`)
            );
            locationsInfo.push({
                position:{
                    lat: dataSet[id][1].lat,
                    lng:dataSet[id][1].lng
                },
                name:dataSet[id][0]         
            })
        }
        Promise.all(data)
        .then(responses => 
            Promise.all(responses.map(response => response.json()))
        )
        .then(locations => {
            locations.forEach((location, index) => {
                locationsInfo[index].year = location.series[0].data[0][0]
                locationsInfo[index].CO = location.series[0].data[0][1]
            })
            resolve(locationsInfo)
        })
    })
}
getLocations()
.then(locations => {
    console.log(locations)
    console.log(locations.length)
})
```

Ahí puedes realizar dentro del `.then` la consulta de tus locaciones.

El problema que el `console.log` te muestre los resultados parece ser un problema de sincronización de google chrome o de webkit, te dejo un [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays) donde hablan de el tema.

Comment: ush man muchísimas gracias,  hay cosas que no entiendo de tu código pero se que revisando con calma la documentación lo entenderé, pero si de casualidad me llego a varar en algo que no entienda de tu código te puedo preguntar por acá?, por lo del console.log ya ahora lo reviso con calma, milgracias.

Comment: si, no hay problema. No olvides darle respuesta aceptada.